# perl one-liner to add a double quote on a regex match

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to come up with a a perl one liner for doing the following?
Add the missing double quote `"` for all the strings that match

```
"DNR for ABC-FULL*"
```

From:

```
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11002,576,"Crane, IN",207,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11003,577,"Crane, IN",208,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11004,578,"Crane, IN",209,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11005,579,"Crane, IN",210,NOW(),1,1),
```

To:

```
(NULL,137,"DNR for JRE-FUL11002,576","Crane, IN",207,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for JRE-FUL11003,577","Crane, IN",208,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for JRE-FUL11004,578","Crane, IN",209,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for JRE-FUL11005,579","Crane, IN",210,NOW(),1,1),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capturing group or `\K`

```
$ perl -pe 's/(,"DNR for ABC-FUL[^"]*),/\1",/g' file
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11002,576","Crane, IN",207,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11003,577","Crane, IN",208,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11004,578","Crane, IN",209,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11005,579","Crane, IN",210,NOW(),1,1),
```

OR

```
$ perl -pe 's/,"DNR for ABC-FUL[^"]*\K,/",/g' file
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11002,576","Crane, IN",207,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11003,577","Crane, IN",208,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11004,578","Crane, IN",209,NOW(),1,1),
(NULL,137,"DNR for ABC-FUL11005,579","Crane, IN",210,NOW(),1,1),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<="DNR for )[^-]*(-[^,]*)
```

Try this.Replace by `JRE$1"`or `JRE\1"`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/42

or
     You can use `\K` feature of perl

```
"DNR for \K[^-]*(-[^,]*)
```

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/43